# C Lang - What is wrong with my code?

Tags: c

With my below code, I am trying to a have the percent of the overall class grade shown. I have everything set up and it seems as though everything works up until the sum. This is my first assignment in C and I cannot see what is wrong.

I just need it to give the percentage as the output but instead it gives me 1490.0000 when I use 1 as the score, but the output should be 1% (22 assignments / 2200 points)

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, // integers for variables
   q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, t1, t2, t3, t4, sum, total = 2200;
   float per;

   printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 1: "); // Assignment statements
   scanf("%d", &a1);
   printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 2: ");
   scanf("%d", &a2);   
   printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 3: ");
   scanf("%d", &a3);   
   printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 4: ");
   scanf("%d", &a4);
   printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 5: ");
   scanf("%d", &a5);   
   printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 6: ");
   scanf("%d", &a6);      
   printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 7: ");
   scanf("%d", &a7);
   printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 8: ");
   scanf("%d", &a8);   
   printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 9: ");
   scanf("%d", &a9);   
   printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 10: ");
   scanf("%d", &a10);
   printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 11: ");
   scanf("%d", &a11);   
   printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 12: ");
   scanf("%d", &a12);       
   printf("\nEnter the score for Quiz 1: "); // Quiz statements
   scanf("%d", &q1);
   printf("\nEnter the score for Quiz 2: ");
   scanf("%d", &q2);  
   printf("\nEnter the score for Quiz 3: ");
   scanf("%d", &q3);
   printf("\nEnter the score for Quiz 4: ");
   scanf("%d", &q4);
   printf("\nEnter the score for Test 1: ");
   scanf("%d", &t1);
   printf("\nEnter the score for Test 2: ");
   scanf("%d", &t2);
   printf("\nEnter the score for Test 3: ");
   scanf("%d", &t3);   
   printf("\nEnter the score for Test 4: ");
   scanf("%d", &t4);  

   sum = a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9 + a10 + a11 + a12 +
   q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5 + q6 + t1 + t2 + t3 + t4;

   per = (sum * 100) / total;
   printf("\nPercentage : %f", per);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: They invented these things called arrays so that you don't need to write the same code out 12 times for the assignments, etc.  However, there's a chance that you've not covered those yet — but 22 entries is a bit cruel if they've not covered arrays yet.

Comment: You've forgotten to ask for the scores for quiz 5 and quiz 6, so you get quasi-random garbage in your calculation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Jonathan, I understand but I've just started the class and the professor wants everything written the long way for the time being!

Comment: Note that scanf does not recover from invalid input. Therefore you should normally *always* check its return value, or your program might do unexpected things.

Comment: @Erdowi since your question is not generally useful (it was just about a bug  that you yourself would have found if you looked carefully enough at the code, no need to even read any manuals or so), the question is not useful as a general reference and 5 people have voted to close the question so that it doesn't get any more spam answers.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala This is my first post, how would I go about closing it? I do not see it under edit.

Comment: @Erdowi closed already :D that's what the on hold means

Comment: @AnttiHaapala My mistake, thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to read in values for quizzes 5 and 6. Therefore, the values for `q5` and `q6` are not defined, and trying to use them lead to so-called *undefined behavior*, which is C slang for "anything can happen". This is why you get so large values for  `per`.

It's easy to fix though: just add these lines reading in the variables q5 and q6, and your code should be fine:

```
printf("\nEnter the score for Quiz 5: ");
scanf("%d", &q5);
printf("\nEnter the score for Quiz 6: ");
scanf("%d", &q6);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Can't believe I missed that. Is there any tricks to minimizing the amount of zero's that show up to the right of the decimal?

Comment: @Erdowi Use `%.0f`, where you can replace 0 with whatever number of decimals you want.

Comment: There is this thing called "close votes" too.

Comment: What are "close votes"?

Answer (score 2):

```
you forgot to take input from user of Q5 and Q6 which I have added in that           lines and rest of all are right    
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, // integers for      variables
q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, t1, t2, t3, t4, sum, total = 2200;
float per;

 printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 1: "); // Assignment statements
 scanf("%d", &a1);
 printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 2: ");
 scanf("%d", &a2);   
 printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 3: ");
 scanf("%d", &a3);   
 printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 4: ");
 scanf("%d", &a4);
 printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 5: ");
 scanf("%d", &a5);   
 printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 6: ");
 scanf("%d", &a6);      
 printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 7: ");
 scanf("%d", &a7);
 printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 8: ");
 scanf("%d", &a8);   
 printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 9: ");
 scanf("%d", &a9);   
 printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 10: ");
 scanf("%d", &a10);
 printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 11: ");
 scanf("%d", &a11);   
 printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 12: ");
 scanf("%d", &a12);       
 printf("\nEnter the score for Quiz 1: "); // Quiz statements
 scanf("%d", &q1);
 printf("\nEnter the score for Quiz 2: ");
 scanf("%d", &q2);  
 printf("\nEnter the score for Quiz 3: ");
 scanf("%d", &q3);
 printf("\nEnter the score for Quiz 4: ");
 scanf("%d", &q4);
 printf("\nEnter the score for Quiz 5: ");
 scanf("%d", &q5);
 printf("\nEnter the score for Quiz 6: ");
 scanf("%d", &q6);
 printf("\nEnter the score for Test 1: ");
 scanf("%d", &t1);
 printf("\nEnter the score for Test 2: ");
 scanf("%d", &t2);
 printf("\nEnter the score for Test 3: ");
 scanf("%d", &t3);   
 printf("\nEnter the score for Test 4: ");
 scanf("%d", &t4);  

 sum = a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9 + a10 + a11 + a12 +
 q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5 + q6 + t1 + t2 + t3 + t4;

 per = (sum * 100) / total;
 printf("\nPercentage : %f", per);

 return (0);
}
```

Comment: You must explain the change.  You're right, but no explanation is no good.